# Is it possible to search all *.xlsx files on the file system for a certain string?

Tags: libreoffice, search

Is it possible to search all *.xlsx files on the file system for a certain string?
I have LibreOffice installed.

Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Grep is you best friend!</s>

```
grep -rnwl '/path/to/somewhere/' -e 'pattern'
```

- `-r` or `-R` is recursive ( it is to mention that `r` option is lazy; traverses depth-first, than stops after the first directory, while `R` is greedy; will traverse the entire tree correctly)
- `-n` is line number
- `-w` stands for match the whole word.
- `-l` (lower-case L) can be added to just give the file name of matching files.

You can add some flags to make things easier.

- `--include` used to search the pattern in files which have the chosen extensions:

  ```
  grep --include=\*.{xlsx,docx} -rnw '/path/to/somewhere/' -e "pattern"
  ```
- `--exclude`: this will exclude searching all the files ending with some extensions:

  ```
  grep --exclude=\*.o -rnw '/path/to/somewhere/' -e "pattern"
  ```
- `--exclude-dir`: used to exclude one or more directories. For example, this will exclude the dirs dir1/, dir2/ and all of them matching *.dst/:

  ```
   grep --exclude-dir={dir1,dir2,*.dst} -rnw '/path/to/somewhere/' -e "pattern"
  ```

**Credit:** [How do I find all files containing specific text on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16957078/8128190)

**EDIT:**
*As [@steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver) mentioned in the comments, I noticed that this method does not works with .xlsx files.*

However, there is another way using [xlsxgrep package](https://pypi.org/project/xlsxgrep/).
You can download it by running:

```
pip install xlsxgrep
# or
pip3 install xlsxgrep
```

To use it, run:

```
xlsxgrep "PATTERN" -H -N --sep=";" -r /path/to/folder
```

Comment: @steeldriver, you're right. Sorry I posted the answer without testing it with .xlsx files.
I'll remove it. Thank you for notifying me.

Comment: @steeldriver, I fixed it, thank you again.

Comment: I don't have pip or pip3. Is there another way to install?

Comment: @AlLelopath, you can install pip3 by running: `sudo apt install python3-pip`

Comment: Upvoted as "useful" however testing with a simple file puzzlingly only finds 2 out of 3 strings...

Comment: Thank you @steeldriver for the feedback. As for testing, I tested it with a random file from the internet and it worked. May be it needs to change the flags or separators... Or simply the package needs more improvements.